# Arranging hierarchical Data by Levels

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, recursion

I Have a data set or array that looks something like

```
[               
  "foo",        
  "bar",        
  [             
    "gum",      
    "ball",     
    [           
      "fat",    
      "rubber", 
    ],          
    "zoo",      
    "topia",    
  ],            
  "ant",        
  "elephant",   
  "grass",      
  [             
    "hopper",   
  ],            
]
```

and i want a function to group them by their levels or depth. Something like:

```
[
   "level 1" => ['foo','bar','ant','elephant','grass'],
   "level 2" => ['gum','ball','zoo','topia','hopper'],
   "level 3" => ['fat','rubber'],
]
```

**Edit** I clarified the source data as it seemed to cause some confusion

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a SQL guru and you don't show anything about the database so here is a recursive PHP function:

```
function get_levels($array, $level=1) {

    $result = array();

    foreach($array as $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $result += get_levels($value, $level+1);
        } else {
            $result[$level][] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

print_r(get_levels($array));
```

Comment: exactly what i needed. Thanks. I would upvote you but, you know, low reputation

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT LENGTH(value) - LENGTH(REPLACE(value, '-', '')) as level, GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(value, '-', '')) as groups
FROM test
GROUP BY level;
```